# A different font for epigraph

Tags: epigraphs

I would like to use a different font for all the epigraphs (say veroldstyle from kpfonts), whereas the main document uses another font. I refer to the epigraph package.

How can I accomplish this? I cannot use XeTeX (lack of competence).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How do you generate the epigraphs at the moment? Which document class do you use?

Comment: I use the memoir class and generate epigraphs using \epigraph{Thank you}{Very Much}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, using the `\pretocmd` command, from the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathabx}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\fontfamily{jkplkvos}\selectfont\em}{}{}
\makeatother
%
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}
\setlength\afterepigraphskip{2\baselineskip}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{For the Snark \emph{was} a Boojum, you see.}{Lewis Carroll, \emph{The Hunting of the Snark}
}

This is the last verse of \emph{Lewis Carroll}’s poem \emph{The Hunting of the Snark (An Agony in 8 Fits),} first published 1876.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: one tiny complaint ... the long "s" was never used as the final letter of a word, as far as i know.  see the tugboat article "[the rules for long s](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100west.pdf)".  (otherwise, a delightful example.)

Comment: @Barbara Beeton: I agree with you  (and I don't have this problem with Sabon Next LT Pro, which is an Opentype font). For my excuse: I didn't even know which variant of kpfonts I loaded (I don't use kp fonts  personally), and the doc isn't very explicit. As the O.P. insisted on ‘very old style’ , I looked at an .fd file with a name ending in `vos` to have the exact name of a family. Note that in the epigraph, all nouns have first letter uppercase, so it's indeed very old style…

Comment: You get the short s by writing s= in place of just s @barbara beeton.

Comment: That should be automatic.

Comment: But for my case, I get away with it... since this is just short quotations from Montaigne's essais https://archive.org/stream/essaisnouvelle01montuoft#page/viii/mode/2up that I need. Automatic solution will be nice of course.

Comment: As I said, an Open type font can do that automatically (I once tried to set a proof of the Marriage lemma more or less in the style of Euler, and used Sabon Next  with historic ligatures, and long s).